# C# windows application using Ubuntu

Tags: c#, ubuntu-10.04

I am interested in C# windows application development. But now that I have shifted to Ubuntu I am no longer able to do it. Is there a way other than virtual box to develop a C# windows application in ubuntu??

Comment: Wow, under what rock have been hiding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there's the [Mono Project](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) but if you want the Microsoft .NET implementation you need Windows.

Comment: And if I use virtual box to install XP, .net will need  a lot of resources na. wont it be too slow? My Ram is 2 GB...

Comment: Yeah it might be slow indeed.

Comment: Okay no other way will opt to virtual box then :(

Comment: How about dual boot? Running an OS from the metal will be faster than virtual box.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in [Mono Project](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page).

It is an open source, cross-platform, implementation of C# and the CLR that is binary compatible with Microsoft.NET. However Mono is not totally up-to-date with lates releases of .NET Framework. It is a mix of .NET 2.0 - .NET 4.0 features.

The Mono project focuses on compilers and runtime libraries and does not directly provide an IDE like Visual Studio. Check [here](http://www.mono-project.com/Monodevelop) to check available solutions.